# What is the best way to store a recursive data structure?

Tags: c++, data-structures

What is the best way to store a recursive data structure in a program? (in C++)

I'm reading data from file, and want to keep it in memory while I validate the data and the user can manipulate it. It will then be written back to file.

I have a many `value`s I wish to store, and each `value` can be a `string`, `List` (== `vector`, `array`...), or a `Table` (==`dictionary`, `unordered_map`, `associative_array`... (the key is always a `string`)).

In the `List` and `Table`, I can store `string`s, `List`s, and `Table`s. I don't know a nesting depth until runtime, but it can be arbitrarily deep.

I've found some examples of containers that can contain themselves (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67865145/stdvariant-of-a-container-that-contains-itself, https://godbolt.org/z/f4dW3raMr), but am wondering if there is a different way.

Any pointers, tips, or resources will be gratefully received.

Edit:
"Best" is probably best described as ease of implementation and runtime performance.

Input files will be anything from a few hundred kb to a hundred Mb.

Comment: Define "best", in particular specifying whether you care most about runtime performance, memory size and/or type safety in your code. _You can't have them all_.

Comment: Object databases are a thing, but they're a complex and spiky thing with many non-obvious trade-offs. There are strong differences of opinion and entire books about how to do them right.

Comment: This decision requires both more context and nuance than this question reveals.

Comment: I would be cautious about conflating recursive relationships with recursive structures.  recursive structures are usually quite complex to implement and inefficient to query.    The same relationships can often be represented far more easily and efficiently using  flatter table structures

Answer (score 3):

If it's merely recursive and can be represented as a tree or directed acyclic graph: do what everyone else does and serialize to JSON. If that's not adequate for performance, try protobuf? Or otherwise come back with a more *specific* problem.

If it's actually cyclic: you have a more serious problem. You have to label nodes (e.g. with unique ID numbers), break cycles when serializing, then when de-serializing you have to keep track of places where a cycle should be and re-construct them once you've loaded all the nodes.

Comment: Serialisation is easy. I'm after the deserialisation route. It isn't cyclic.

Comment: If you use JSON, deserialisation is no problem, there will be a library for that.

Comment: If it's not cyclic, what's the problem?